# Hazelcast Nodejs Client Connection Refused

Tags: node.js, hazelcast

I am trying to run the basic example code provided in the "Using the Client" section of https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-nodejs-client

I am getting a connection refused error. I tried this on both my Mac and my PC machines with the same result. They are running Node v6.9.1. I do not have any special firewall settings. Even tried turning of the Windows firewall completely.

Is there something I am missing?

```
[DefaultLogger] WARN at ClientConnection: Could not connect to address localhost:5701
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5701
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5701 }

Unhandled rejection Error: Unable to connect to any of the following addresses: localhost:5701
at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jennie Lyn\node_modules\hazelcast-client\lib\invocation\ClusterService.js:95:33)
at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)
```

First i created an empty node project then:

```
npm install hazelcast-client --save
```

Then created one js file with:

```
var HazelcastClient = require('hazelcast-client').Client;
var person = {
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 42
};
var map;
HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient().then(function (hazelcastClient) {
    map = hazelcastClient.getMap("personMap");
    map.put(1, person).then(function (val) {
        // prints previous value for key `1`
        console.log(val);
    });
    map.get(1).then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    })
});
```

That's all the documentation says to do. Is there something else that needs to be done to start a single client cluster on the localhost using hazelcast-client for nodejs?

Comment: Maybe sounds stupid but the cluster node(s) are running?

Comment: In the example given in the docs doesn't it start a single node instance by default? If not how to start the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start

- download latest Hazelcast distribution from https://hazelcast.org/download/
- unzip to any folder
- start Hazelcast member using startup script /bin/start.sh

  - you can use samples now

[image: start hazelcast node]

Let me know if it works

Cheers, 
Vik

Comment: In the java version there is no need to run a separate executable, that's why I was confused. Maybe it seems obvious, but i wish it was mentioned in the node client intro where the code sample was.